# What special precautions must I make for docker apps running as pid 1?

Tags: linux, docker, init

From what I gather, programs that run as pid 1 may need to take special precautions such as capturing certain signals.

It's not altogether clear how to correctly write a pid 1.  I'd rather not use runit or supervisor in my case.  For example, supervisor is written in python and if you install that, it'll result in a much larger container.  I'm not a fan of runit.

Looking at the source code for runit is intersting but as usual, comments are virtually non-existent and don't explain what's being done for what reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good discussion [here](http://vagga.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pid1mode.html):

- When the process with pid 1 die for any reason, all other processes
  are killed with KILL signal
- When any process having children dies for any reason, its children are reparented to process with PID 1
- Many signals which have default action of Term do not have one for PID 1.

The relevant part for your question:

> you can’t stop process by sending SIGTERM or SIGINT, if process have not installed a signal handler

Comment: I think you're right.  The main thing is that normally you don't need to catch sigterm.  But for a pid 1 process, it needs a sigterm handler.  And if it spawns any other processes, it needs to handle those during a term as well.

Comment: Found a thorough explanation of a traditional /sbin/init script, with examples in Ruby that cover everything a PID 1 should be able to do https://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/init/